# When do we know we should use a symbol?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, ruby-on-rails-3

Here is a code I am trying to understand and the confusing part for now is the :product_id in the code, specially the ":" part of ":product_id"
My question is how should we know we should use that ":" ?

```
def up
    # replace multiple items for a single product in a cart with a single item
    Cart.all.each do |cart|
      # count the number of each product in the cart
      sums = cart.line_items.group(:product_id).sum(:quantity)

      sums.each do |product_id, quantity|
        if quantity > 1
          # remove individual items
          cart.line_items.where(product_id: product_id).delete_all

          # replace with a single item
          item = cart.line_items.build(product_id: product_id)
          item.quantity = quantity
          item.save!
        end
      end
    end
  end
```

Comment: In the snippet you give it doesn't matter. In general look at the methods documentation to see if it expecting a symbol or a string (or what difference it makes between them)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Symbols are just pointers to an object containing its name while strings are always different objects.

If you are going to repeat a name many times in your code then use one symbol which is the equivalent of using just one object.

For example if you use the string `"France"` a 100 times in your code, you would prefer to use `:France`. The advantage is that in the first case you would instantiate a 100 objects and in the second case just one.

In your example, maybe you are getting confused because `product_id: product_id` is a Hash represented in JSON style. This would be the equivalent of `:product_id => product_id`

Answer (score 3):

Symbols:

- are basically string constants
- are created once. i.e. `:product_id` will be the same object whenever you use it. Hence they save memory. On the other hand if you write `"product_id"` multiple times, you are basically creating as many string objects
- cannot take the benefit of Reg-ex and interpolation(mostly) unless you use a to_s method on a symbol

In a nutshell, use symbols for short string constants which you don't need to process or modify.

*Eg: Symbols are great for keys in Hashes etc. Get it?*